# Excel Function to flag when number of switches during a 7-day rolling period is greater than 4

Tags: excel

Say I have a column with dates and a column with on and off representing a switch.

[image: Columns]

If I wanted to look at a rolling 7-day range for any time the switch was off more than 4 times what function would I use? I was trying CountIf but the range is tricky as it has to be any period of 7 days.

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far

Comment: I've been looking at COUNTIFS because theres basically two criteria that has to be met, one being that OFF is read and the other that the difference between the dates is less than or equal to 7. The last part is the tricky one as I have no idea how to do a moving range. =COUNTIFS(I:I,"OFF",H:H,SUM(H1,-H2)<7) is what I have so far and I know its completely wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this where you have 2 separate COUNTIFS criteria on the same date column should work.

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(I1:$I$10000,"OFF",H1:$H$10000,"<="&H1,H1:$H$10000,">"&H1-7)>4,"OFF more than 4 times in the past 7 days","")
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the 7-day period roll? Currently it only analyzes 7 days from the first date in cell H1. But say the first cell is 3/15/19 and every cell after: 2nd, 3rd, 4th, .. etc. is 2/15/19. The function should flag it as being off more than 4 times in 7 days because you have the switch turning on and off many times during 2/15/19 but it currently doesnt since 2/15/19 isnt 7 days from 3/15/19.

Comment: =IF(COUNTIFS(I1:$I$10000,"OFF",H1:$H$10000,"<="&H1:H10000,H1:$H$10000,">"&H1:H10000-7)>3,"OFF more than 3 times in the past 7 days","")

This ended up working to do the rolling period. The only thing I changed was the &H1 range to include the entire H1 column